# How to replace regex to array element in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I met with the following problem. I wanted to replace a tag on the name of the corresponding element of the array string. Maybe a little awkwardly explain it, so I will show you the code:

```
var test = [];
test['some'] = 'Some test';
var content = '{some}';
document.write(content.replace(/{([^}]+)}/g, test[RegExp.$1])); // It doesn't work
document.write(test[RegExp.$1]); // It work
```

Now my question: why the replace tag is not getting the string held in the test ['some'] (get undefined)? During the second attempt to get normal string 'Some test'. How to fix it to properly converted tags when converting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape `{ and }` as they both are special regex symbols:

Use this regex:

```
/\{([^}]+)\}/g
```

**EDIT:** You need `String#replace` with custom function handler:

```
repl = content.replace(/\{([^}]+)\}/g, function($0, $1) {return test[$1];});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but unfortunately it still does not work. I've tried both document.write(content.replace(/\{([^}]+)\}/g, test[RegExp.$1])); and document.write(content.replace(/\{([^}]+)\}/g, test["$1"]));

Answer (score 1):

Check this <kbd>**[demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zfm4P/)**</kbd>

#### JavaScript

```
var test = [];
test['some'] = 'Some test';
var content = '{some}';
document.write(content.replace(new RegExp('/{([^}]+)}/','g'), test['some'])); 
document.write(test['some']);
```

#### Result

```
{some}Some test
```

Here i check your <kbd>**[regexp](http://regex101.com/r/nS6oJ2)**</kbd> work perfect
Hope this help you!